# In C++, if need to use a break statement, is 'while' loop preferred over 'for' loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, break

I believe performance is almost the same. But is there any advantage on using while loop for code readability and/or maintainability?

Comment: You might try a more specific question and perhaps provide an example of how you're using both.  This seems rather opinion based.

Comment: A `for` loop is a more generalized form.  `while` is a strict subset of `for`.

Comment: a while loop is the foundation of all looping constructs. If you ever implement a compiler, you'll see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the `for` and the `while` loop constructs are interchangeable. Any problem which can be solved with one can also be solved with the other.

However, they send a different message to the human reader of the code.

A `for` statement says "we will do this a predetermined number of times" while a `while` statement says "we don't know how often we are going to do this. We will do it until we got what we want".

Comment: Thanks to all for your comments. Good information. This answer is the closest to what I was looking for. I will check mark this as the answer. However, I would still love to see some practical guideline like, .. pick 'while' loop in these cases, 'for' loop in these cases and doesn't matter in all other cases..., that guideline I can apply when I need to pick one of them. One example is that, if there is a predetermined max number of times to iterate through but want to exit if some condition is met. Should I use 'for' loop with a 'break', or a 'while' loop without a 'break'?

Comment: Again, this question is on a readability and/or maintainability perspective only, as indicated in my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'While' is convenient when you don't know the size of a container. For example, if you need to iterate through a list.

Comment: You can use a for loop for that.  `for(Node* n = head; n; n = n->next) {}`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja , yes, you are right. I've not thought of that.

Comment: But it is convention to use while loop when size is not known or want something to be checked before entering the loop. For loop is a count based loop, so the size is usually determined. This is however by convention.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep in mind that your code should be clearly understandable at first glance, if possible. On that basis my personal opinion is (ordered by descending importance):

1. If `break`-ing out of a loop or using the content of a loop counter variable outside the loop always write a little comment about that.
2. If you're coding in a team try to mimic their style if appropriate. Find out whether coding guidlines are in place.
3. Use `while(true){...if(...)break;...}` to build an endless loop as it looks more professional compared to `for(;;){...if(...)break;...}` or `for(;true;){...if(...)break;...}`.
4. If you realize that statements about loop exiting or incrementing the counter (or iterator) are going to be placed *inside* the loop's body - maybe even several times - use `while` to avoid that anybody skimming over your code is going to believe that the loop is being controlled just by its head. Consider that a potential reader of your code might be unfamiliar with the language of your comments so the code has to speak for itself.
5. Use C++11 range-based `for` loops whenever appropriate.